# What is the meaning of W and T on a camera's zoom buttons?

Tags: terminology, camera-basics, zoom

On every conventional digital camera (excluding the models with detachable lenses), there are buttons to zoom in and out with **W** side and **T** side.

When you press  **`W`**, the lens zooms out. The lens zooms in when you press **`T`**

I want to know what do these letters, `W` and `T` mean.

Comment: I'd vote to close as a too-basic/look-in-the-manual question, except when I did a quick search, it looks like there's a lot of people asking it, so I don't think it hurts for us to have an answer.

Comment: I tell PPl its T for towards it W for way from it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

These letters refers to zooming depth as follows,

> - **W** = Wide angle
> - **T** = Telephoto

Read more about [wideangle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wide-angle) and [telephoto](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telephoto) in the tags.

Comment: The name "telephoto" includes "tele", which means "far off" or "over a distance" so it literally means "long distance photography"

Answer (score 15):

The W stands for Wide angle. The T stands for Telephoto.

This has been asked around the web, for example here:

[Yahoo! Answers: What does W T button (zoom) stands for in zoom lens cameras?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080104005637AAK37Ti)
[Tech-Recipes: Why are Camera Zoom Buttons Labelled W and T?](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/13176/why-are-camera-zoom-buttons-labelled-w-and-t/)

Answer (score -4):

W = **W**ithdraw

T = **T**owards

These are one way to remember.